# How can I monitor the CPU usage of each application

Tags: cpu, process, windows-server-2008-r2, cpu-usage, performance-monitor

Sometimes I need to understand each application is running and consuming more CPU Resources than others and stop it.
is there any Sw to monitor  this?

Comment: How can we answer when you don't specify your operating system?

Comment: I have win2008R2

Comment: Windows Performance Toolkit: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-42-WPT-CPU-Analysis

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the Windows taskmanager ?
Alternatively, you can use the (also Windows) resource manager (run -> resmon).

[Sysinternals](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx) procmon is also widely used.